# Using Extensions in firefox selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I am trying to use an extension in selenium for geckdriver and have found that I need to use `FirefoxProfile`. From here though, I am lost on what exactly to do. I can't find much help online. Here is what I have, but I get a `System.TypeInitializationException` error.

```
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

            string workingDirectory1 = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

            profile.AddExtension(workingDirectory1 + "\\anticaptcha.xpi");

            options.Profile = profile;
           
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

            
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like addExtension method needs some corrections it accepts File as a argument and not a string